# How to bind a panel's data context to parent object in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, panel, datacontext

Having this in XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Example"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             >
    <Grid x:Name="RootPanel">

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

how to get an equivalent of this in a code-behind:

```cs
public Example()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.RootPanel.DataContext = this;
    }
```

There are many examples of how to bind object's data context to it's own self, e.g.

```xml
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

or how to bind a property **to a property** in the parent:

```xml
SomeOtherText="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
```

but I couldn't find an answer on how to bind to the parent itself.

Comment: combine `"{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` and `"{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"`, and you get `"{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"`. changing Datacontexts in usercontrols is BAD idea

Comment: Thx for the answer, somehow it seemed to not work that way when I myself checked it before posting a question. As to the warning, fortunately, I still know too little about WPF to understand this transgression's repercussions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to the parent `UserControl` using a relative source binding.

```
<Grid x:Name="RootPanel" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Example}}}">
```

The [relative source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource?view=net-5.0) will set the source of the binding to the `Example` parent control.

> By default, bindings inherit the data context specified by the DataContext property, if one has been set. However, the RelativeSource property is one of the ways you can explicitly set the source of a Binding and override the inherited data context.

The [`Path` is empty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.path?view=net-5.0) in this case, which will not bind to a specific property, but the control itself.

> To bind to an entire object, you do not need to specify the Path property. For more information, see "Specifying the Path to the Value" in [Data Binding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-binding-overview?view=netdesktop-5.0).